# WordPress php mysql errors - errcode: 13 permission denied

Tags: permissions, mysql, php, localhost

I'm developing a WordPress based website using the latest XAMPP release from Oct 9 2019 with Apache 2.4.41, MySQL/MariaDB 10.4.8 and php 7.3.10 using localhost on a Windows 10 machine.

Since updating XAMPP I have been besieged with errors similar to the following:

```
PHP Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/6): Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql35b0_ee_0.MAI' (Errcode: 13 &quot;Permission denied&quot;) in C:\xampp\htdocs\amc\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2007
```

WordPress database error Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp#sql35b0_ee_0.MAI' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied") for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_options` made by wp_reschedule_event, wp_schedule_event, _set_cron_array, update_option

I have checked the permissions of \xampp\tmp 50 times and authenticated users, system, administrators and users all have full control. I have also deleted Wordpress and the associated data base and data tables several times yet the error on delete permission errors continue.

I'm seriously at a loss so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Brought to moderator attention - this belongs on Wordpress stackexchange.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out a solution? I'm experiencing a similar problem.